# Parsing a string with multiple levels of key value pairs

Tags: python, strings

I need to write a part of the program which will work with a string, find in it some substrings and copy they to dictionary. Example of the string:

```
thestring ='\
#: somethings\nchars0 "substr0"\nchars1 "substr1"\n\n\
#: something\nchars0 "substr2"\nchars1 "substr3"'
```

so it have current substrings 'chars0' and 'chars1' which I know and some random substrings like 'substr0'...

But it is a small problem - on the start of the string anothoer structure:

```
'chars0 ""\nchars1 ""\n"words\\n"\n"else words\\n"\n ... '
```

and then structured string like above.

I know only number of this substrings with words, but I'm not interested in this subtrings, I need substrings only from structured part of the string.

If print the string, we get this:

```
chars0 ""
chars1 ""
"some words\n"
"else words\n"
... 

#: something
chars0 "subtring"
chars1 "else substring"

...
```

How can I optimize search of it? 
(I think that it is good to try find() string method or rfind() because of end of the string is structured)

Comment: What do you mean by "structured part of the string?"

Comment: I mean this: '#: somethings\nchars0 "substr0"\nchars1 "substr1"\n\n#: something\nchars0 "substr2"\nchars1 "substr3"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic way to parse this string might be

```
thestring ='\
#: somethings\nchars0 "substr0"\nchars1 "substr1"\n\n\
#: something\nchars0 "substr2"\nchars1 "substr3"'

for token in thestring.split('\n'):   
  if "#" in token:
    handler.heading(token)    
  elif "" == token:
    handler.section(token)
  else:
    handler.body(token)

print handler.dictOfDicts
```

This will print either

```
{'#: something': {'chars0 ': 'substr2', 'chars1 ': 'substr3'},
'#: somethings': {'chars0 ': 'substr0', 'chars1 ': 'substr1'}}
```

or

```
heading: #: somethings
key: chars0
value: substr0
key: chars1
value: substr1
section:
heading: #: something
key: chars0
value: substr2
key: chars1
value: substr3
```

depending on if `handler` is set to `StringStructure()` or `StringPrinter()`, respectively.  Where

```
class StringStructure:
  dictOfDicts = {}  
  currentHeading = ''
  def heading( self, token ):
    self.currentHeading = token
    self.dictOfDicts[self.currentHeading] = {}
  def section( self, token ):
    pass
  def body( self, token ):
    key, value, junk = token.split('"')
    self.dictOfDicts[self.currentHeading][key] = value    

class StringPrinter:
  dictOfDicts = ''
  def heading( self, token ):
    print 'heading: ' + token
  def section( self, token ):
    print 'section: ' + token
  def body( self, token ):
    key, value, junk = token.split('"')
    print 'key: ' + key
    print 'value: ' + value
```

This is brittle because it assumes you will always have two items in the body, two levels of keys, and won't produce the most meaningful error messages when the format of your string is wrong.

Comment: If you want to elegantly deal with arbitrary levels of keys see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369723/multi-level-defaultdict-with-variable-depth-in-python